# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] unethicalreading in

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, soapserver

I use this PHP Code :

```
class CNJ {
    private $urlWsdl;
    private $soapClient;

    public function __construct()
    {             
        
        $urlWsdl = getenv('CNJ_URL');  // HOMOLOGAÇÃO = 'https://esaj-xefe.tjsp.jus.br/mniws/servico-intercomunicacao-2.2.2/intercomunicacao?wsdl';
       
        try {
            
            $this->soapClient = new \SoapClient($urlWsdl, array (
                'exceptions' => true,                
                'trace' =>1,
                'connection_timeout' => 5000,               
                )
            );
        } 
        catch (SoapFault $exception) {
            echo "Mensagem de Erro: ". $exception->getMessage();
            return;
        }
    }


 public function entregarManifestacaoProcessual($numeroProcesso, $arquivo){
       
        if (getenv('AMBIENTE') == 'PRODUCAO'){
            $tipo_documento = 'xx'; //
        } else {
            $tipo_documento = 'xx';
        }
        $dados = array();

        $dados['idManifestante']=getenv('CNJ_USER');
        $dados['senhaManifestante']=getenv('CNJ_PASSWORD');
        $dados['numeroProcesso']=$numeroProcesso;           
        $dados['documento']['tipoDocumento']=$tipo_documento;
        $dados['documento']['dataHora']= date('YmdHis');
        $dados['documento']['mimetype']= 'application/pdf';
        $dados['documento']['nivelSigilo']='0';
        $dados['documento']['descricao']='Comprovante de Depósito';
        $dados['documento']['tipoDocumentoLocal']=$tipo_documento;
        $dados['documento']['conteudo'] = base64_decode($arquivo);
        $dados['dataEnvio'] = date('YmdHis');
              
        $response = $this->soapClient->entregarManifestacaoProcessual($dados);        
       
        return $response;
    }
```

And get this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] unethicalreading in /var/www/html/xxx/xxx.php:75 
> Stack trace: 
> #0 /var/www/html/xxx/xxx.php(75): SoapClient->__call() 
> #1 /var/www/html/xxx/xxx.php(92): CNJ->entregarManifestacaoProcessual() 
> #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/xxx/xxx.php on line 75

Already clean the PHP tmp folder without sucess.

It appears that the error started after the certificate used for the digital signature of the sent
file was changed.

How can I fix this error?